# What are the complex differentiable functions that take only real values?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $ f = u + iv: \Omega (\subset \mathbb{C} ) \to \mathbb{C}$ be
> complex differentiable in an open disc $\Omega$ and takes only real
> values, then prove that $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ is a constant
> function.

Since it is complex differentiable on $\Omega$, using Cauchy Riemann equations we get,

$f'(z) = u_x(z) + i v_x(z) = v_y(z) - i u_y(z)\;\; \forall \; z\in \Omega \;\;\;\ldots (1)$

Now, because $f$ only takes real values on $\Omega\rightarrow v(z) = 0 \;\; \forall \;z\in \Omega \rightarrow v_x(z) = v_y(z) \;\;\forall \; z\in \Omega$

Hence, using $(1)$, we can say that

$v_x(z) = 0 \;\;\forall \; z\in\Omega  \rightarrow Im(f'(z)) = 0 \;\;\forall \;z\in \Omega$

$v_y(z) = 0 \;\;\forall \; z\in\Omega  \rightarrow Re(f'(z)) = 0 \;\;\forall \;z\in \Omega$

All this together mean that $f'(z) = 0 \;\;\forall\; z\in \Omega \rightarrow f(z) $ is constant on $\Omega$

Is my proof correct?
If it is correct, then what is the need for $\Omega$ to be open disc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have proved (correctly) that $f'(z)=0$. But that does not imply that $f$ is a constant. For example if the domain is a union of two disjoint open disks then $f=1$ on the first disk and $0$ on the second disk gives a counter-example. If the domain is connected then $f$ must be  a constant. So, instead of  a disk we can take any open connected see as the domain of $f$.